# Android items move from ActionBar to options menu when changing orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a fragments based app where some fragments have additional actions that I want to put as buttons into the `ActionBar`, while some do not have any such actions. I have created an xml menu file that contains all the items for all the fragments and I show/hide at runtime depending on which fragment is currently shown using a combination of:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(some_id);
item.setVisible(false);
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(some_other_id);
item.setVisible(true);
```

The problem is that when I am viewing a fragment that has no menu items, if I change device orientation and then change to a different fragment - with menu items - those items do not show up in the `ActionBar` but are only accessible using the device's "Menu" button.

All menu items are set as `android:showAsAction="always"` in the xml file, yet they consistently fail to show up in the `ActionBar` if the last orientation change was done while viewing a fragment with no menu items. This happens during both portrait-to-landscape and landscape-to-portrait changes.

How can I force the items to be displayed in the `ActionBar` at all times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

1. Per the [ActionBar design document](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), even a 10" tablet in landscape will only show a maximum of 4 items in the Action Bar per the below chart:
   [image: Maximum number of icons in the ActionBar]
2. Assuming you are under the maximum number of items that show in the `ActionBar`, if you want Fragments to add items to the `ActionBar` when they appear and remove when they hidden, you do not need to manually show/hide items within a single xml menu file, but instead add the items in each individual `Fragment` per the [Fragments - Adding items to the Action Bar guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar).

Comment: Thank you for a quick and rather comprehensive answer. I only have have 1, 2, or zero items in each fragment, so first point should not cause issues. Will take a look into the second point and see if that works out.

Comment: Yes! The per-fragment menu items do not exhibit this behaviour, works great and easier to maintain too.