# Force action bar to make it look split in landscape mode, as in google play

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-tabs, navigationbar

By default when I turn the screen on my device to landscape, the action bar changes from being split with tabs to navigate, to be contracted in one with Spinner to navigate.

I want to show the split action bar in landscape mode, as in google play. Or show tabs  instead the spinner.

I use actionbarsherlock

Comment: To enable split action bar, simply add uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" to your <activity> or <application> manifest element.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html. I am not sure this helps coz this is action bar and not actionbarsherlock.

Comment: @Raghunandan
Well it works on portrait orientation, but in landscape the action bar collapse in one. that doesn't happens in google play app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862445/android-items-move-from-actionbar-to-options-menu-when-changing-orientation. In landscape mode click menu and check if the items appear there.

Comment: @Oscar Méndez have you found the solution. I want this also

Comment: @Qadir Hussain Yes, is a library called "PagerSlidingTabStrip" check it out https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: That is layout at the bottom, no actionbar